# Sequelize model query with [or] not retrieving data

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a project that I am working on. I build the database models with sequelize. Not I am running the controller. In one of the methods, I want to pass in a `userId` into the url as a parameter. With that `userId`, I want to check and see if any of the records has the passed in `userId` in the `friendedId` or `frienderId` fields within the databse.

I am using the `[or]` in the filtering to make that query return all records and it currenty returns none.

this is the controller method:

```
getByUser: (req, res) => {
        let user_id = req.params.userId;
        Friend.findAll({ where: {[or]: [{ frienderId: user_id }, { friendedId: user_id }]}})
            .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
                res.status(200).send(response.dataValues)
            })
            .catch()
    },
```

this is the  model:

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const { database } = require('../index');
const { User } = require('./User');


const Friend = database.define(
    "friend",
    {
        id: {type: seq.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        status: {type: seq.STRING, allowNull: false, 
                 validate: {isIn:[['Pending', 'Accepted']], isAlpha: true}
        },
        favorite: {type: seq.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValues: false, 
              validate: {isIn: [['true', 'false']]}
        },
    },
    {
        createdAt:  seq.DATE,
        updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
    }
)


Friend.belongsTo(User, {as: 'friender'})
Friend.belongsTo(User, {as: 'friended'})


database.sync()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected the Friend model to database')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Issue connected the Friend model to the database: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
    })


module.exports.Friend = Friend;
```

Comment: I think the problem is your double Friend.belongsTo(User,{...}) in database's schema

Comment: please post the raw query generated by `findAll`

Comment: So how would i be able to basically check to see if a passed in user id is either in the `friender` or `friended` columns. I can not figure this out. @peterzinho16